# Interspire Template

Tags: php, javascript

In Interspire     I copy a template & paste it then rename it &  I customize it according to my theme but when i go into admin & in admin when i click on design mode then there should be site open for making changes but in my new template it is not open in proper way  & I am not be able make changes in this mode please tell me why it is happening in my new template only. in standard template it is working properly. Please tell me the region why this is happening when i select my own template in design mode then there is an error in error-console error is  :---  undefined  xt/javascript">

Answer (score 0):

After you paste the template, make sure the file is readable by the web server. Insufficient right is the main reason you are not able to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean about the copy and paste. But the best way to create an Interspire theme is to use the default folder or one of the other ready made templates and do the following:.

Let's say you decide to use the "default" theme. Copy the entire folder somewhere on your computer and rename the folder to the name you'd like your theme to have.

If you are changing specific files, copy those files from _master to the correct directories in your new theme folder.

Upload to your server and activate.

Your theme file names have to remain the same. i.e. you can't rename the files themselves, only the top level theme folder they are in.

Then you can open up the files and make your changes inside of them.

Even though it's possible. I stopped using the built in theme editor once we took the step to create our own theme. For one, doing so kept removing our custom panels when we hit the "save" button.